# Query 2 similar tables SQLITE

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, mysql-python

So there are 2 tables in my database.

```
staff:
name      age    mail
John      20     john@john.john
Robert    25     robert@robert.robert


customers:
name     age    mail
Bob      21     bob@bob.bob
Mara     20     mara@mara.mara
Trisha   20     trisha@trisha.trisha
Melina   23     melina@melina.melina
```

If I want to select **everything** from **customers** where **age** is **20** I use this:

```
extracting = mydb.execute("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE age = '20'")
20s_users = extracting.fetchall()

for i in 20s_users:
  print(i)
```

And the output in python is

```
('Mara', '20', 'mara@mara.mara')
('Trisha, '20', 'trisha@trisha.trisha')
```

But I want to select this thing from BOTH tables and combine them...

What query command should I use in order for my output to be:

```
('John' '20' 'john@john.john')
('Mara', '20', 'mara@mara.mara')
('Trisha, '20', 'trisha@trisha.trisha')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a `UNION ALL` clause such as

```
extracting = mydb.execute("""
                           SELECT * 
                             FROM
                             (
                              SELECT * FROM customers
                              UNION ALL
                              SELECT * FROM staff
                             ) AS cs  
                            WHERE age = 20  
                          """)
```

where quotes wrapping up matching values for `age` column are removed considering the data type as numeric.

Comment: Yes, that indeed worked. I reached page 2 on google trying to find this + looking trough some other people questions on stackoverflow but found nothing that contains this UNION ALL.

Thank you a lot for your response!